# A piecewise function defined on $[0,3^n]$

Tags: functions, inequality

I encountered this piecewise function recently: let $f(x)$ be defined on $[0,3^n]$ where $n$ is a positive integer. First, let
\begin{equation*}
f(0)=0,\quad f(0<x\leq 3)=2n+1-x.
\end{equation*}
Subsequently,
\begin{equation*}
f(3^kp<x\leq 3^k(p+1))=f(3^k(p-1)<x\leq 3^kp)-1
\end{equation*}
in which $p$ is not divisible by $3$. For $n=3$ the graph is here:

[image: f(x) for n=3]

and n=4 here:

[image: f(x) for n=4]

Is there a name for this type of functions? I have a specific question here: if $x_1+x_2+x_3=3^n+\epsilon$ for small $\epsilon>0$, is it true that $\min\{f(x_1)+f(x_2)+f(x_3)\}$ tends to infinity as $n\to\infty$? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out by myself.

Write $x$ in base $3$ as $x=(x_nx_{n-1}\cdots x_1)_3$, then
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=2n+1-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i.
\end{equation*}
Now let $a=(a_n\cdots a_1)_3$, $b=(b_n\cdots b_1)_3$ and $c=(c_n\cdots c_1)_3$. Then $a+b+c+d=3^n+1$ for instance, becomes
\begin{align*}
a_1+b_1+c_1&=3x_2+1\\
a_2+b_2+c_2+x_2&=3x_3\\
\cdots & \cdots\\
a_n+b_n+c_n+x_n&=3
\end{align*}
Adding the above equations and notice that $0\leq x_i\leq 2$ for $i=2,3,\cdots,n$. It follows that
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i+b_i+c_i)=4+2\sum_{i=2}^n x_i\leq 4+4(n-1)=4n.
\end{equation*}
Consequently,
\begin{equation*}
f(a)+f(b)+f(c)\geq 6n+3-4n=2n+3\to\infty\;\; as\;\; n\to\infty.
\end{equation*}